# Print in new line, java

Tags: java, printing, new-operator, println

I have following code :

```
    System.out.println(" | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
```

I use println to create a new line. Is it possible to do the same using \n or \r?
I tried to add \n to the second println statment and continue printing with the print method but \n does not create a new line.

any ideas?

Comment: Call `System.out.println();` repeatedly :P

Comment: I wonder why you have problems to simply write `System.out.println("\n)";`
The "\n" considers as escape sequence for C/C++/C# and Java aswell.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");//This will retrieve line separator dependent on OS.

    System.out.println("line 1" + newLine + "line2");
```

Comment: Since Java 7 you have `System.lineSeparator()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29

Comment: is `System.out.println();` looked down upon? Doesn't this do the same thing?

This is my second day in Java, came to find best practices.

Comment: it does except that it adds line separator at the end

Comment: Great! This is really useful for me.

Answer (score 35):

```
System.out.println("hello"+"\n"+"world");
```

Answer (score 14):

Your best shot would be with

```
String.format("%n")
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%n");
```

It is supposed to print a newline character, depending on the current platform, so it's perfect for the console.

If you are printing to a file, then it depends.

Comment: This is far by the best answer since it address the problems discussed:
1. Platform and 2. Java Versions.

Answer (score 9):

It does create a new line. Try:

```
System.out.println("---\n###");
```

Comment: In the past, the Apple Mac requirse lines to be separated by '\r', So its better to write system independent code , check my solution

Comment: He's talking about "new line". Had he requested "new line + carriage return" I'd pointed him to \r\n :) If we're going to be picky, then I'd suggest using a StringBuilder rather than concatenating strings.

Comment: For `"line 1" + newLine + "line2"` using a StringBuilder explicitly would be counter-productive. The compiler can optimize this by itself.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the built in line separator. The advantage is that you don't have to concern  what system you code is running on, it will just work.

Since Java 1.7

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

Pre Java 1.7

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Answer (score 7):

You might try adding \r\n instead of just \n.  Depending on your operating system and how you are viewing the output, it might matter.

Answer (score 5):

`\n` creates a new line in Java. Don't use spaces before or after `\n`.

Example: printing `It creates\na new line` outputs

> It creates
>   a new line.

Comment: where does it say that using \n in java will use the correct newline, such as \r\n on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Windows, instead of \n use \r\n (carriage return + line feed).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Case1:
System.out.println(" 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9" + "\n" + "----------------------------");

//Case2:
System.out.printf(" 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9" + "\n" + "----------------------------");

//Case3:
System.out.print(" 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9" + "\n" + "----------------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `System.out.println();` without any parameter terminates the current line by writing the line separator string.

> Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n') (1).

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--

Answer (score -2):

"\n" 
this is the simple method to separate the continuous String

Answer (score -2):

```
System.out.print(values[i] + " ");
//in one number be printed
```

Comment: number will be printed in one line like 1 2 3 4 5    for new line we can use \n

Comment: Does not answer the question. Even worse - attempts to solve a problem unrelated making it only confusing. Moreover - there is no explanation at all!