# how to multiple integers on a text without adding or doing any multiplications

Tags: java

This is what I got so far, ignore the fact that stuff is missing...

```
    if (fnum > snum && fnum > tnum && snum > tnum){
        System.out.println(fnum\n snum\n tnum);
```

So basically I want to have fnum snum and tnum all in a lane however I can't just do like:

```
System.out.println(fnum, snum, tnum);
```

because its giving me an error.

Any help? I can't figure this out at all and google searches are not being too helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variables and strings:

```
System.out.println(fnum + "\n" + snum + "\n" + tnum);
```

or if you want [cross platform new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008248/1290264):

```
String ln = System.getProperty("line.separator"); // OS independent new line
System.out.println(fnum + ln + snum + ln + tnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.print(fnum);
System.out.println();
System.out.print(snum);
System.out.println();
System.out.print(tnum);
```

or you can also try `System.out.println(fnum+"\n"+snum+"\n"+tnum);`

`System.out.println();` forces the next output to go to next line while in `System.out.print` the next output stays in the same line

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf`

```
System.out.printf( "%s, %s, %s", fnum, snum, tnum );
```

And if you want each of the number on a new line, use:

```
System.out.printf( "%s\n, %s\n, %s\n", fnum, snum, tnum );
```

**Refer to**:  [java.io.PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)