# How do i get my System.out.prints to line up under each other?

Tags: java

I want all the responses to line up under each other

example:

x=y

y=x

ect...

not

x=y y=x ect...

```
// Julian Vizcarra
// Lab 05 question 2
public class Lab05_02 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
// Enter an integer
System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
int number = input.nextInt();

//compute math
int ok = number/5;
int ok2= number/6;

//If statement
if (number % 5 == 0 && number % 6 == 0){
 System.out.print("Is " + number + " divisible by 5 and 6?" + " True "  );}  

    else {System.out.print("Is " + number + " divisible by 5 and 6?" + " False "  );  }

if (number % 5 == 0 || number % 6 == 0) {
 System.out.print("Is " + number + " divisible by 5 or 6?" + " True "  );}

    else {System.out.print("Is " + number + " divisible by 5 or 6?" + " False "  );}

if (number % 5 == 0 ^ number % 6 == 0) {
System.out.print("Is " + number + " divisible by 5 or 6, but not both" + " True");}

    else {System.out.print("Is " + number + " divisible by 5 or 6, but not both" + " False");}
}
}
```

my output is:

Enter an integer: 60

Is 60 divisible by 5 and 6? True Is 60 divisible by 5 or 6? True Is 60 divisible by 5 or 6, but not both False

Comment: try use println() in stead print

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print in new line, java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008223/print-in-new-line-java)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`System.out.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) instead of `System.out.print()`.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println() or System.out.println("\n") do what you want

Comment: Typo in the answer, your second one should probably be "print" instead of "println":System.out.println("value") or System.out.print("value\n")