# How to print 10 numbers per line in java

Tags: java

I have a simple but hard problem and wanted to get your help on this. 
This is the code:

```
int i = 0; 
while (i < 100) {
      i++; 
     System.out.print(i);
}
```

This is the real issue that I'm having, how do I control the println to display how many numbers per line that I want so I don't just see `100` numbers in a row straight?
Btw please if at all possible, don't give me the answer but help me to answer it myself instead.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008223/print-in-new-line-java

Comment: `if (i % 10 == 0) { System.out.println(); }`?

Comment: Check the value of `i` and when you get to the number you want (you can use modulus operator to determine if i is at the count you want) just print a new line.

Comment: The problem is that its going to print 100 in a row, i just wanted to split them into rows of 10 or whatever i wanted. i tried madprogrammer but it just gave me 102030405060708090

Comment: @Dumbfounded because you need to add spaces too. Right now you're just printing each number right next to each other. Try `System.out.print(i + " ");` instead, with MadProgrammer's tip too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert object array to string array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018750/how-to-convert-object-array-to-string-array-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while` loops? Why not use `for` loops? They are much better in this kind of situation i.e. when you want to repeat something a known number of times.

You can use a nested for loop to make this happen:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10 ; j++) {
        System.out.print (counter);
        System.out.print (" "); // I think it is best to have spaces between the numbers
        counter++;
    }
    //after printing 10 numbers, go to a new line
    System.out.println ();
}
```

Comment: sweeper do i have to use 2 for loops just to make it print 10 per line? I just wanted it to print like a calender ie.. 1234567890, next line under number 1 it would be 11121314151617181920 then next line would be 21 all the way to 100, can i use 1 loop instead?

Comment: Yes you can! Just like MadProgrammer has said in the comments, you can use one for loop to print 1 to 100. Every iteration, you check if `i % 10 == 0` i.e. If `i` is divisible by 10. If it is, then go to a new line. @Dumbfounded

Comment: Thank you very much on this, it did try it but it didnt work at first but i was blind and couldnt see now I do. I tried looking on the net for just a straight answer to this but everybody had a huge problem but i just wanted 1 part of the problem so I asked here. now that I have it thanks to madprogrammer and sweepers help, here is the code for future reference, int i = 0; while (i < 10) { i++; if (i % any number == 0) System.out.println(); System.out.println(i);

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking on the tick ✅ on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
    for(int number = 0; number <= 100; number++) {
        if(number % 10 == 0 && number > 0)
            System.out.println(number);
        else
            System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
```

This would create 10 rows of 10 numbers.

Comment: I found the answer to both. just 1 for loop and 2 if statements

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (i%10==1){
     System.out.println("");
 }
```

Comment: Hey Firas, welcome to SO!  When answering it helps to be a little more complete, so maybe edit your answer to show how this would work in context of the original problem.  Also, it's good to add an explanation of *why* your solution works, especially in this case where they have asked for direction.   Last tip, check out the formatting tools.  adding three back-ticks in a row will start a code block, and three more will close it.